# Rails fetch with limit order and "not"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app i use rails 4.

And i need to fetch as i do now data, but all except one params[:id], now i have such code:

```
@vip_cars = Car.order(created_at: :desc, is_vip: :desc).limit(100).sample(4)
```

and i try something like:

```
@vip_cars = Car.order(created_at: :desc, is_vip: :desc).not(id: params[:id]).limit(100).sample(4)
```

but it didn't work. What i do wrong? how to fetch data with order, limit, sample and not in rails 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write as

```
Car.order(created_at: :desc, is_vip: :desc)
   .where.not(id: params[:id])
   .limit(100).sample(4)
```

Read [`#not`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not)

> Returns a new relation expressing WHERE + NOT condition according to the conditions in the arguments.

*Remember `#not` always work in conjunction with `#where`.*